# different behaviours of sendto/send on linux and mac os x

Tags: linux, macos, sockets, operating-system

Question 57.1 from The Linux Programming Interface:
Write programs to show that if a sender transmits datagrams to a UNIX domain datagram socket faster than the receiver reads them, then the sender is eventually blocked, and remains blocked until the receiver reads some of the pending datagrams.

Here's my code:

```
 // 57.1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "../lib/error_functions.h"

void sender(int sender_sock) {
  printf("at sender sock\n");
  char buf[] =
      "hello world byte";
  long bufsize = sizeof(buf);

  for (;;) {
    printf("sending data...\n");

    if (sendto(sender_sock, buf, bufsize, 0, NULL, 0) != bufsize) {
      errExit("partial write. Exiting\n");
    }

    printf("sent\n");
  }
}

void receiver(int receiver_sock) {
  printf("at receiver sock\n");
  char buf[1];
  long bufsize = sizeof(buf);

  for (;;) {
    printf("ready to read!\n");
    if (recvfrom(receiver_sock, buf, bufsize, 0, NULL, 0) != bufsize) {
      errExit("partial read. Exiting\n");
    }
    printf("read!\n");

    sleep(1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // 1. create a unix domain datagram socketpair
  // 2. fork a child process (which'll be the receiver)
  // 3. send stuff from parent process till the child blocks (using sendto and
  // recvfrom)

  int fds[2];
  int status = socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, fds);
  if (status == -1) {
    errExit("socketpair creation failed");
  }

  if (fork() == 0) {
    // child logic
    printf("%d will execute receiver logic with socket: %d\n", getpid(),
           fds[1]);
    receiver(fds[1]);
  } else {
    // parent logic
    printf("%d will execute sender logic with socket: %d\n", getpid(), fds[0]);
    sender(fds[0]);
  }
}
```

On linux, the program behaves correctly, and the sender is blocked. But on mac os x, the sender returns error:

```
ERROR [ENOANO No buffer space available] partial write. Exiting
```

Why is there a difference between the two systems. Also, how can we make it behave in the same manner (make sendto blocking)?